# Best cartridge for deploying static html/javascript files to openshift?

Tags: angularjs, openshift

I want to deploy a pure angular-js frontend appication to openshift. This application contains only html/css/js files.

What is the best cartridge that I can use, php5, tomcat, nodes.js?

Thanks

Comment: maybe just apache2 or nginx.

Comment: Is that cartridge available on openshift? It is not mentioned here: https://www.openshift.com/developers/technologies

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The best is PHP for a simple HTML + JS app. PHP is the lightest weight cartridge we have. It is what the evangelists use for HTML apps. For example - http://talks.thesteve0.com is running on OpenShift in a PHP cartridge and is just a reveal.js site.

Comment: I was expecting this answer, I already created a php cartridge and it works simple indeed.

Comment: I have a similar need in I want to put Pelican onto OS, and it just needs HTML.  So where would I put the .html files, in the root folder for the app?

Comment: If you use a PHP app the answer is yup

Comment: @TheSteve0 would I need to create my index page in the index.php file or can I just delete it and create my own index.html and configure some settings?

Comment: Go ahead and delete it. Think of it like you are running an Apache server with mod_php installed.